# TortoiseSVN downgrade issue from 1.8 to 1.7

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I was using the TortoiseSVN 1.7.11 client (Windows 7). I updated it to 1.8 and then it worked for some time with the 1.8 release. But other machines with which I'm working are still using 1.7.11, and I can't upgrade them so I thought of downgrading to 1.7.11. Now it's not working at all. I took a fresh checkout and it still asks to upgrade the working copy.

When I click this option, it says "can't upgrade as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory. Missing default entry. I tried removing registries and delete configuration information from `%appdata%` folder too, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Uninstall TSVN. Reinstall version 1.7. Delete your working copy. Create new working copy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I took checkout in a new directory itself. Then also it pops up "upgrade working copy" message.

Comment: You have not got rid of 1.8 yet. Complete uninstall, reboot, reinstall tsvn 1.7

Comment: reboot solved the problem, Thanks. I didn't expect that.

Comment: Reboot often needed because tsvn is hosted by explorer and you need a boot cycle to kick out the old and bring in the new

Answer (score 12):

For people who don't read the comments first.

- Backup any changes you have in your working directory
- Uninstall TortoiseSVN 1.8
- **Reboot**
- Install TortoiseSVN 1.7
- Do a fresh checkout into a new directory
- Manually copy any needed changes from your backup to new directory

Answer (score 1):

Ther is no need to check out to a separate directory and lose local changes.

After downgrading to TortoiseSVN 1.7 it is possible to recreate the SVN 1.7 format by:

- Removing all the .svn directories

  ```
  for /d /r . %d in (.svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
  ```
- Checkout using `--force`:

  ```
  svn co --force <repo_url> <local_dir>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- You have not performed a fresh checkout with the TortoiseSVN 1.7 client. If you had, you wouldn't get working copy format errors.
- Remove TortoiseSVN 1.8.0, install TortoiseSVN 1.7.x, and checkout a fresh working copy.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have taken a fresh checkout in a fresh directory.